# Arduino - Powered water bottle code not working as I expect it to

Tags: arduino

My group and I are trying to create a smart Arduino-powered bottle for a project, which reminds users to drink water on a regular basis.

What I'm trying to do is to check the distance between the ultrasonic sensor and the water level. If the distance remains the same for more than an hour, the serial monitor displays the word "bad". Else it returns the word "good". However, when I run this code, it outputs the word "good" even when the distance remains the same for more than 5000 milliseconds.

Note: In the code, I have assigned 5000 milliseconds to the interval variable instead of an hour for quick results.

Note 2: This is only a test code and is far from complete. In order to move on, I need to make this work.

```
// defines pins numbers
const int trigPin = 8;
const int echoPin = 7;

// defines variables
int maxrange = 20;
int minrange = 0;
long duration, distance;

long previousmillis = 0;
long interval = 5000; //1 hour = 3600000ms;
unsigned long currentmillis = millis();

void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
}

void loop() {
  // Clears the trigPin
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  //Converting the distance to cm
  distance = duration / 29 / 2;


  if (currentmillis > interval) {
    if (distance == distance) {
      Serial.println("Bad");
      Serial.println(distance);
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("Good");
    Serial.println(distance);
  }
}
```

What is wrong with this code? Please let me know.

Comment: When do you imagine `distance == distance` would be false?

Comment: I'm sure I've made mistakes. If you don't mind could you please help me with the corrections? Thank you.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I didn't test it.

```
 // defines pin numbers
    const int trigPin = 8;
    const int echoPin = 7;

    // defines variables
    int maxrange = 20;
    int minrange = 0;
    long duration, distance;

    long previousmillis = 0;
    long interval = 5000; //1 hour = 3600000ms;
    unsigned long currentmillis = millis();

    void setup() {
      pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
      pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
      Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
    }

    void loop() {
      int temp = 0;
      // Clears the trigPin
      digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(2);

      // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
      digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(10);
      digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

      // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
      duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

      //Converting the distance to cm
      distance = duration / 29 / 2;
      if (currentmillis > interval) {
        temp = duration / 29 / 2;
         Serial.print("Temp:");
         Serial.println(temp);
        if (temp == distance) {
          temp = 0 ;
          Serial.println("Bad");
          Serial.println(temp);
        }
      } else {
        Serial.print("Good:");
        Serial.println(distance);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you check this code and tell me what is the distance you are getting on serial monitor.for Temp and distance variable.

Comment: I just get an error : _exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno_ I'm sure I have selected the right board and port. I don't know why this error is coming

Comment: @Devika.S in the below code given by anime, just change the following line  **int distance** to **int distance1** .The error is coming because the function name and the variable name are same **distance** change any one of them you will not get any error.
The above code given by me it is compiling without any error just check the IDE settings once again.

Answer (score 0):

Concept : For example, if the object is 10 cm away from the sensor, and the speed of the sound is 340 m/s or 0.034 cm/µs the sound wave will need to travel about 294 u seconds. But what you will get from the Echo pin will be double that number because the sound wave needs to travel forward and bounce backward.  So in order to get the distance in cm we need to multiply the received travel time value from the echo pin by 0.034 and divide it by 2.

First, you have to define the Trig and Echo pins. In this case they are the pins number 9 and 10 on the Arduino Board and they are named trigPin and echoPin. Then you need a Long variable, named “duration” for the travel time that you will get from the sensor and an integer variable for the distance.

In the setup you have to define the trigPin as an output and the echoPin as an Input and also start the serial communication for showing the results on the serial monitor.

In the loop first you have to make sure that the trigPin is clear so you have to set that pin on a LOW State for just 2 µs. Now for generating the Ultra sound wave we have to set the trigPin on HIGH State for 10 µs. Using the pulseIn() function you have to read the travel time and put that value into the variable “duration”. This function has 2 parameters, the first one is the name of the echo pin and for the second one you can write either HIGH or LOW. In this case, HIGH means that the pulsIn() function will wait for the pin to go HIGH caused by the bounced sound wave and it will start timing, then it will wait for the pin to go LOW when the sound wave will end which will stop the timing. At the end the function will return the length of the pulse in microseconds. For getting the distance we will multiply the duration by 0.034 and divide it by 2.  At the end we will print the value of the distance on the Serial Monitor.

```
// defines pins numbers
int desired_time_limit=5000;
const int trigPin = 9;
const int echoPin = 10;
// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;
void setup() {
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
}

float distance(void)
{
// Clears the trigPin
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
// Calculating the distance
distance= duration*0.034/2;
return distance;
}

void loop() {
float a;
a=distance();
if(millis()>desired_time_limit)&&(a!=distance())
  printf("Bad");
else
  printf("Good");   
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I've already understood the concept. I need more help with this part: **What I'm trying to do is to check the distance between the ultrasonic sensor and the water level. If the distance remains the same for more than an hour, the serial monitor displays the word "bad". Else it returns the word "good". However, when I run this code, it outputs the word "good" even when the distance remains the same for more than 5000 milliseconds.**

Comment: When I run it I get this error: exit status 1
'float distance()' redeclared as different kind of symbol

Answer (score 0):

`currentmillis` is never set or reset in the loop. Because it is initialised at the start, the value for `currentmillis` will be very low. As such, `if (currentmillis > interval)` will always be false, leading to the 'Good' branch.

An approach is to set `currentmillis = millis()` at the start of each loop iteration. Compare `currentmillis - previousmillis` to `interval`. When the 'Bad' branch is activated, reset `previousmillis=currentmillis`.

Comment: @anime -? Please clarify your comment. This is the answer as to why the code is not working (in conjunction with the "distance == distance" comment on the OP,